# Looking for a way to hint the users how to flip the pageViewController

Tags: ios, user-interface, uipageviewcontroller

I am using PageViewController in my app.

In the beta some users complained that they didn't understand that they can flip pages.

I saw that in some apps there is an hint animation that curls the right top corner of the page.

Is that something I can achieve with PageViewContoller or is it a custom animation?
If you know I would love a direction.

Thanks

Shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in my app is add a segmented control into the top right of the navigation bar, with a left pointing triangle and a right pointing triangle. Now users know they can page through the view. Once they know this they can use gestures later to do the same thing - its more of a hint of functionality than required.

The problem with animations etc is that they help the first time user, then annoy the long time user. Getting help "overlays" to be useful but not annoying is an art I have yet to master.

Comment: Good solution but you can set something like that the help or tutorial is only shown for first time the application runs and then after on some specific button touch the help is shown.

Comment: Well, its more complicated. You probably want to remember if the user has ever seen it. Then you have app updates - do you show it again then or not? So you now need a user default, and need to be sure you don't override it or delete it, and then as you modify your app over time need to add and delete this as you may have multiple pages that need this state info. BTW, ask me how I know all this :-)

Comment: Because its what I do in my app (this is a common American English joke - "ask me how I know this" - it means I did it and learned, usually the hard way and with some pain. You will need heuristics to decide if the person really has seen the hint, then save that knowledge in user defaults, maybe for multiple different views, then  later in time decide if you need to show the assistance again on app updates etc.